# PrimeNG <p-menu> how to keep click menu item selected (Angular 7)

Tags: html, dom, primeng, angular7

I am using primeNg  component in angular 7 project.

```
<p-menu [model]="items" ></p-menu>
```

while dealing with this component we don't have access to its internal structure to show click menu item as selected. to push active class when a certain menu will be selected and change its color.

Does anybody have any idea about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research I found a solution to deal with this problem.

> Html:

```
<p-menu [model]="items"  (click) = "activeMenu($event)"></p-menu>
```

on click of menu component i have added activeMenu($event) method. $event carries clicked DOM element which is the menu item element.

> Component:

On component, I have written the following code.

```
activeMenu(event) {

let node;
if (event.target.tagName === "A") {
  node = event.target;
} else {
  node = event.target.parentNode;
}
let menuitem = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-menuitem-link");
for (let i = 0; i < menuitem.length; i++) {
  menuitem[i].classList.remove("active");
}
node.classList.add("active")
```

}

Comment: may i know how to get the event.target value if event.target is <span>Text</span>.I need to get selected p-menu text

Comment: Add click event to your span tag

Comment: if more than one instance, above solution will not work. try to inject ElementRef to constructor and use querySelectorAll method instead document.getElementsByClassName("ui-menuitem-link") .

Comment: Hello. While debugging I see the active class was added, but when it finishes the active class is not rendered into HTML. Have you faced something like this?

Answer (score 3):

For PrimeNG 10 I had to do tweak the code by Surendranath the following way:

**Template:**

```
<p-menu [model]="items" (click) = "activeMenu($event)"></p-menu>
```

**Component:**

```
  activeMenu(event) {
    //console.log(event.target.classList);
    let node;
    if (event.target.classList.contains("p-submenu-header") == true) {
      node = "submenu";
    } else if (event.target.tagName === "SPAN") {
      node = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    } else {
      node = event.target.parentNode;
    }
    //console.log(node);
    if (node != "submenu") {
      let menuitem = document.getElementsByClassName("p-menuitem");
      for (let i = 0; i < menuitem.length; i++) {
        menuitem[i].classList.remove("active");
      }
      node.classList.add("active");
    }
  }
```

**Global Style (not Component Style)**

```
.p-menuitem.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Hello. While debugging I see the active class was added, but when it finishes the active class is not rendered into HTML. Have you faced something like this?

Comment: it works fine for p-panelMenu

Comment: .p-menuitem .active {
  background-color: orange;
}

This is how the css should be

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for this SURENDRANATH SONAWANE - first solution that worked for me after trying many others.

In case this helps anyone, I couldn't get my CSS class recognized, had to add the following notation in .css (note the `:host >>>`  prefix)

```
:host >>> .active {
    background-color: #b8ebf5;
}
```

...also, for a default menu item, pre-select it in MenuIItem[] definition by setting styleClass, e.g.:

```
        this.items = [
           {label: 'Search' , url : '/#/query' , styleClass : 'active'}, // Default item
           {label: 'Stats'  , url : '/#/stats' },
           {label: 'User'   , url : '/#/user'  }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Angular 13.0.2` and `Primeng 13.0.0`

I add the following code to myComponent.component.css  **not** global `styles.scss`

```
::ng-deep .p-menuitem-link-active{
  background-color: #FED201!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<p-menu 
    [model]="[
     { label: 'a', command: onClick() ,styleClass : getClassByLabel('a') },
     { label: 'b', command: onClick() ,styleClass : getClassByLabel('b') }
    ]"
><p-menu>
```

ts:

```
  currentModel: any;

  onClick() {
    return (event) => this.currentModel = event.item;
  }

  getClassByLabel(label: string): string {
    if (this.currentModel && this.currentModel.label == label) {
      return 'active';
    }
  }
```

**style**.css:

```
p-menu > div > ul > li.active > a > span {
  color: color:blue !important;
}
```